# How to decrease radio button drawable size?

Tags: android

I have four radio button.

## xml source

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/fragBtn1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_selector"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_img_selector" />
```

## btn_img_selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_btn" android:gravity="center" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/nonselected_btn" android:gravity="center"/>
</selector>
```

## btn_bg_selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/btnPressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/btnNonPressed"/>
</selector>
```

But button image is too big.
I want to decrease a button image size only..(not decrease button size)
For example, I want to scale a button image size 30px * 30px.
Is it possible?

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547412/how-to-decrease-radio-button-size-in-android

Comment: I don't wanna a decrease button size! only button image size...

Comment: I find this solution, see my answer here
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/44310577/6112256](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44310577/6112256)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a solution.
But I find a another solution.

## xml source

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/fragBtn1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_selector"
    android:button="@null"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_selector" />
```

## MyActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mybtn);

    int iconWidth = bd.getBitmap().getWidth();
    int leftPadding = (btn.getWidth() / 2) - (iconWidth / 2);

    btn.setPadding(leftPadding, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Sclae the button

```
<RadioButton
        android:scaleX="0.75"
        android:scaleY="0.75" />
```

Comment: It adds extra margin on left

Comment: @Tanseem: give negative margin on left

Answer (score 3):

Finally found the correct solution :

**Step 1 :** 
Use your **@drawable/selected_btn** or **@drawable/nonselected_btn** as an [INSET DRAWABLE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset) .

**Step 2 :**
Provide padding as desirous.

**Step 3 :**
Yuhuuuu !! You've decreased the size of the radio button image.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it correctly , you should resize your assets accordingly. Otherwise, i'm not sure how to drecrease the button image size without decreasing the button by itself