# Is there a way to adjust the size of a drawable next to a radio button?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I like to give users a choice between three options. I am using a radio group and three radio buttons. I also like to have an image next to each radio button. I have figured out I can use a drawable like the xml code below:

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButtonMom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/mom"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
        android:text="@string/mom"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
```

However, I can't adjust the size of the drawable. So, for smaller screens, things don't look right. Is there a way I can add an image to a radio button and still be able to set the size of the image(in dp)? Can I do this while I still have the radio buttons in a radio group, so that only one can be selected at any give time?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437223/how-to-decrease-radio-button-drawable-size please check this first